# React - 404 not found

Tags: reactjs, flask-mail, react-player

I'm having a problem making requests to my endpoint `/send-email` from React. I have `flask-mail` configured to make the async call.

This is how frontend makes the request:

```
 emailClient(event, index){
  let {clientCount} = this.state;
  var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
    }
  const {userId} = this.props
  const client = this.state.clients[index];
  const data = {
    client: client
  };
  const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/send-email/${userId}`;
  axios.post(url, data, {headers: headers})
    .then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        clientCount: clientCount +1
      });
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    });
  };
```

rendering:

```
  render() {
    const orders = this.state.clients;
    const { clients, youtube_urls, loadedVideosCount, currentPlayingIndex } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="title is-1">Jukebox</h1>
          {this.state.isLoading}
          {
            clients.map((client, index) => {
               /* 
              Obtain preview from state.previews for current artist index 
              */
              const audio = youtube_urls[index]
              /* 
              Render current client data, and corresponding audio url
              */
              return(
                <div key={index}>
                <ul>
                  <li><font color="#C86428">Client: </font><strong><font color="#6f4e37"> { client.name } </font></strong></li>
                  <li><font color="#C86428">Phone: </font><strong><font color="#6f4e37"> { client.phone } </font></strong></li>
                  <li><font color="#C86428">Email: </font><strong><font color="#6f4e37"> { client.mail } </font></strong></li>
                  <li><font color="#C86428">Artist: </font><strong><font color="#6f4e37"> { client.tracks[0].artist } </font></strong></li>
                  <li><font color="#C86428">Track: </font><strong><font color="#6f4e37"> { client.tracks[0].title } </font></strong></li>
                  <ReactPlayer 
                    url={ audio }
                    controls
                    width='50'
                    height='150'
                    onLoaded={() =>
                    this.setState(currentState => ({
                        loadedVideosCount: loadedVideosCount + 1,
                        currentPlayingIndex:
                          loadedVideosCount + 1 === youtube_urls.length ? 0 : -1,
                      }))
                    }
                    onStart={() => this.emailClient(index)} //<--------
                    onEnded={() =>
                    this.setState(currentState => ({
                        currentPlayingIndex: currentPlayingIndex + 1,
                      }))
                    }
                    playing={index === currentPlayingIndex}
                  />
                </ul></div>
              )
            })
          }
      </div>
    )
  };
};

export default Jukebox;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
POST http://localhost/send-email/1 404 (Not Found)
```

endpoint:

```
@task_bp.route('/send-email/<user_id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def send_email(user_id):
   try:
     #business logic
     send_async_email.delay()

     return jsonify(response_object), 200    
   except (exc.IntegrityError, ValueError):
     db.session.rollback()
     return jsonify(response_object), 400
```

`nginx` reverse proxy config:

```
  location /send-email {
    proxy_pass        http://web:5000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
```

'web' and 'client' services, on which mailing services depend, are built like so using `docker-compose`:

```
services:

  web:
    build:
      context: ./services/web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/web:/usr/src/app'

    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@web-db:5432/web_dev 
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@web-db:5432/web_test
      - SECRET_KEY=my_precious
      - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/usr/src/app/project/api/resources/youtube/urls/z.json  
    depends_on:  
      - web-db
      - redis

  client:
    build:
      context: ./services/client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL=${REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}
    depends_on:
      - web
```

and everytime I build them, I do:

```
 $export REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL=http://localhost
```

what could be wrong?

---

> NOTE:

If I post directly to the endpoint using POSTMAN to `http://localhost:5001/send-email/1`, it works.

Comment: Have you read the error? The error says your endpoint isn't found, this doesn't seem related to react or react-player. Is your URL missing the port? (like http://localhost:1234/send-mail/1) ? Do you have an endpoint handler that takes in a user ID at the end of it? is auth failing?

Comment: I use proxy which declares the port `location /send-email {
    proxy_pass  http://web:5000;`

Comment: The error says your URL is `http://localhost`, but the endpoint you're showing us is `http://localhost:5001`

Comment: all other endpoints work with the same config, I don't think thats the point. Maybe `event.preventDefault()`, lke i said on my edit.

Comment: Probably, there is no any argument of `onStart()` callback, so there is no any `event` that you can call `event.preventDefault()` on. `onStart` is not a browser event, so you can't prevent any default handling.

Comment: Update your line "const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/send-mail/${userId}`;". Remove `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}`.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh error persists....

Comment: Could it be that the call is to `onStart={() => this.emailClient(index)} ` passing in just `index`, but the function `emailClient(event, index){` expects `event` and `index` ?

Comment: no..when I pass `index` only, I correct and declare only `index` as argument, remove `event` from `emailClient()` and error persists

Comment: Where does `proxy_pass        http://web:5000` go?

Comment: Your route is `send-email` while your url is sending request to `send-mail` @@

Comment: Browsers send ```OPTIONS``` request to check if the backend server allows cross origin requests or not. For example: if the url you are making an async request to is not in the same domain or not for example http://localhost and http://localhost:5001 are different domains, browser will send an `OPTIONS` request first and post server acknowledging to it then will the browser send the actual post request.

Couple of things to check: 
1) If the proxy pass is passing the request to the correct upstream server
2) You are using correct endpoint from the front end

Comment: Try also to add a slash at the end of the url in React, like so : ```/send_email/${user.id}/ ```, sometimes backend frameworks expect such a trailing slash on the url.

Comment: Are you able post directly to the endpoint using POSTMAN to http://localhost/send-email/1? Without the port.

Comment: no it throws error CANNOT POST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding port `5001` after `localhost:` at client fixed it for me:

```
   const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}:5001/send-email/${userId}`;
```

Console:

```
XHR finished loading: OPTIONS "http://localhost:5001/send-email/1".
```

I still don't get why, since all other dozens of endpoints dispense `5001`, but it is fixed. Any answer that clarifies the reason will be granted the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

In your Nginx frontend webserver configuration, you set up a reverse proxy to pass request to `/send-email` to the web application server with hostname `web` listening on port `5000`.

```
location /send-email {
    proxy_pass        http://web:5000;
```

This means you can request to `/send-email/1` directly.

You noted in your question that an `OPTIONS` request is performed in your browser and gets a `404` response whereas a `POST` is what is expected.

The reason for this is that the request performed with the axios client is a preflighted one.

For [preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests), the browser first makes an `OPTIONS` request to the path to determine if the request is safe to send.

A number of characteristics determine a preflight request, one of which is the value of [`Content-Type` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests) being one other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded | multipart/form-data | text/plain`

Response to a `OPTIONS` request to confirm that a `POST` request is safe must have `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers which say so. For example, the request headers in your `POST` request are:

- `Content-Type`
- `Authorization`

For a confirmation from the server that the `POST` request is safe, response headers for the `OPTIONS` request must be

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, OPTIONS, GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

You could handle this preflight response in your Nginx configuration. For example

```
    location /send-email {
        # ...
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'HEAD, OPTIONS, GET, POST';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400;
            return 204;
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you could handle `OPTIONS` request in your view function

```
from functools import wraps

def cors(f):
    '''Handle preflight OPTIONS request'''
    @wraps
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if request.method != 'OPTIONS':
            return make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))

        response = current_app.make_default_options_response()
        access_control_headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'HEAD, OPTIONS, GET, POST',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '86400',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
        }
        response.headers.extend(access_control_headers)
        return response
    return wrapper

@cors
@task_bp.route('/send-email/<user_id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def send_email(user_id):
    # ...
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I had forgotten to add  `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true` to the function, it was there all along, even before my hack adding the port. Please refer to my edit at `emailClient()` function. I hope it keeps your answer valid.

Comment: All headers set in the `POST` request need to be listed in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` for the  `OPTIONS` response.